# num.split is not a function

Tags: javascript, split, reverse

```
const num= 3849;
function reverseGivenInteger(num){
    return num.split("").reverse().join("")
}
console.log(`Reversed integer is: ${reverseGivenInteger(num)}`)
```

I want to reverse number, what specific thing do I need to correct here
Showing error: TypeError: num.split is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the number to a string first:

```js
const num = 3849;

function reverseGivenInteger(num) {
  return String(num).split("").reverse().join("")
}
console.log(`Reversed integer is: ${reverseGivenInteger(num)}`)
```